# Prevent Related Videos from showing when posting on Facebook.com

Tags: facebook, youtube-iframe-api

I've looked at the the Google API on preventing the related videos from showing up at the end when using the following format:

htts://youtube.com/v/videoID?**rel=0**

and while this does have the effect for the video, it has the unintended consequence of opening the video in a new window, which I DO NOT WANT.

From the share button within YouTube, I see the format to use when posting to facebook is:

https://youtu.be/videoID

I've tried appending the ?rel=0 to it but it seems to have no effect. I've even tried the following but with no success:

https://youtube.com/embed/videoID?rel=0

This last one not only does not work but is meant for only iframe situations and some of code shows up in the facebook post. Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: If you are just sharing YouTube links, then YT is in control of all the OG meta data.

Comment: Agreed that it should be done on YT side, but for some reason it's not working.